# Combining selectRaw and paginate in Laravel

Tags: laravel

I am trying to return paginated results based of the age of users. Laravel throws and error when I use `selectRaw()` in combination with `paginate()`.

Here is the error:

> Illuminate\Database\QueryException : SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'age_months' in 'having clause' (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `ads` having age_months <= 3)

Here is the code:

```
Ad::selectRaw('TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, DATE(ads.birth_date), CURDATE()) AS age_months')
    ->having(\DB::raw('age_months'), '<=', $request->max_age_months)
    ->paginate();
```

As you can see, the `count(*)` overrides the `selectRaw()` making it obsolete. I have tried replacing the `paginate()` with `get()` and it works, and produces this query:

> select TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, DATE(ads.birth_date), CURDATE()) AS age_months from `ads` having age_months <= ?

Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: tell me your logic i will convert it into the Laravel query and also paginated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I was making things way more complicated. I solved it by just using Laravel's `whereDate()`.

```
Ad::whereDate('birth_date', '>=', now()->subMonths($request->max_age_months))
    ->paginate();
```